# Server would not allow ssh connection unless user has entry on /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow

Tags: ssh, debian

I have recently taken over the management of a couple servers. Both servers need to allow ssh connection from `jenkins` user, which is managed by LDAP. Both servers show the user information when I type in `id jenkins`.

I've created a `home` directory for the user in both servers. Both servers contain the same public key in the user's `authorized_keys` file. All permission settings are identical.

When attempting to ssh into `server A` as `jenkins` user, this is what the log shows.

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA KEY
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /jenkins/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /jenkins/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /jenkins/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /jenkins/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /jenkins/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /jenkins/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

When sshing into `Server B` as `jenkins` user from the same server, this is what the log shows.

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA KEY
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to SERVER A ([IP ADDRESS]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env SUDO_USER
debug3: Ignored env SUDO_UID
debug3: Ignored env USERNAME
debug3: Ignored env MAIL
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env SUDO_COMMAND
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env SUDO_GID
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
```

Basically, `jenkins` user can ssh into `Server A`, but not `Server B` when both servers contain the same home directory for the user. I've had to modify the `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` file on `Server A` to get it to work.

What is going on here?

Comment: Can you provide the output of `getent passwd jenkins` on both machines?

Comment: Can you verify that the integration with LDAP works properly and that the LDAP jenkins user can be displayed from Server A?

Comment: Thank you guys. Running `getent passwd jenkins` showed me that the home directory for the user is actually set differently in both servers.

Answer (score 0):

I ran `getent passwd jenkins` as David suggested and it showed that the home directory path for the user is set differently in both machines. This solves my question.